# Pymongo get mongodb field datatype

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is there a way to get mongodb's collection's datatype for each field using pymongo ?

I would mainly need it to identify the fields with data type "array".

Comment: You can write a query using the operator `$type` to identify or check a field's data type.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make use of the `$type` operator and mention the the type of the document you want to fetch.

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

c = MongoClient()
db = c["db"]
col = db["collection"]

# Fetch records from `collection` where `key1` is of type `array`
for x in col.find({"key1": {"$type": "array"}}):
    print(x)
```

Refer to the below link to know more on how to use `$type` operator

Comment: Thank you. it worked :) I had to change the type from array to object as the data was having array of Json element